# Proximity alert firing alert only once

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, locationmanager

I want to get the current location and add a proximity alert to that location. When ever I exit or enter a radius around the current location. As I am getting the current location's latitude and longitude and adding the proximity alert, I get an alert as soon as I register. But I am not getting when I exit even if i am on the foreground. I have registered my reciever in the manifest.

This is my Activity.

```
    public class GeoFencer extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locMan, locManForProximitySensor;
    private Intent i;
    private PendingIntent pService;
    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        setContentView(R.layout.geo_fencer_layout);
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        context = this;

        locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManForProximitySensor = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        i = new Intent("com.packagename.proximity");
        pService = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0   , i, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.geofencemenu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_geo){
            if(locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            }
            else if(locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is disabled. Please Enable.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



        locManForProximitySensor.addProximityAlert(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10, -1 , pService) ;
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Proximity alert added (" + location.getLatitude() + ", "+ location.getLongitude() + ")");
        locMan.removeUpdates(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My Reciever

```
   public class ProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        String message  = " ";
        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
            message = "You are entering your point";
        }
        else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
            message = "You are exiting your point";
        }


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("CompanyName")
                .setContentText(message);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in Adavance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add one of this flags: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT .

Comment: Sorry can you please explain your answer. Why should it enter onLocationChanged more than once. Once the proximity alert is added, it doesnt expire until I remove it right? So it should fire the pending intent however. And also if I take it out, I will be adding several alerts. I want to register alert for only one location(the current location at the time user clicks the menu item.

Comment: ops sorry...i didn't notice your onOptionsItemSelected. I think then the problem is in your pending intent. You should add one of this flags: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: Tried that too. No change. :(

Comment: my last solution is to change the name of the i
line i = new Intent("alert2"); after this: if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_geo){ 
and recreate your pending intent with a different intent ..(it's not important the name of the intent like "com.packagename.proximity" it is just an id.

Comment: Can you explain me why?

Comment: from android Dev:
if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

So the "name" in the intent is just an "id" to use the pending intent.Usually you put the package name because you want access only from your app

Comment: Hey simas. Changing the flag actually worked. If you change the answer, I will accept it.